# How to remove liftAjax.js?

Tags: lift

Using lift 2.4, all my rendered templates end up including a script tag at the bottom for liftAjax.js.  I am not using any ajax functionality, and removed the jquery stuff from my bootstrap.  How can I get rid of this extra markup from my pages?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ajax_request/liftAjax.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function() {liftAjax.lift_successRegisterGC();});
var lift_page = "F2025216344212IYC4Z";
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This handles lifts function cleanup so that Lift can determine when particular server side functions are in use on the page or not. Its essentially an optimisation and I would not encourage you to disable it.

If however, you insist on disabling it, then you need to add the following to your boot.scala:

```
LiftRules.autoIncludeAjax = session => false
```

Comment: Isn't possible to do that for a single page only?

Comment: But you can't rely on it anyways as lots of people have javascript disabled.  Is lift really designed to generate slower loading pages, creating a worse end-user experience, just to save the lift developers from having to store server side closures properly?  Even if we left it in, our target audience is security professionals, fewer than 30% of our visitors have javascript enabled by default.  How much of a problem is this likely to cause?  Is it only a problem if we use anonymous functions for form callbacks?

Comment: IMHO, the above comment is not constructive at all. The overhead of this feature is tiny compared to the benefit; when an application has been in production for a long time without being turned off. It's an optimisation yes, of course, but without it you will slowly see the memory usage of the application rise over time. It's slow, but it will in all likelihood happen if you make heavy use of the server-side function binding. MAybe this isn't a problem for you, maybe it is. Better to be informed though.

@AloisCochard - no its not possible to turn it off on a single page only. Sorry.

Comment: How is it not constructive.  Like I said, less than 30% of our visitors have javascript enabled, noscript exists and people use it.  If lift relies on optional client side behavior to do garbage collection then that is a serious problem.  And I genuinely would like to know if this will be a problem only if we're using anon functions for our form callbacks, so I can avoid the problem if using named functions will work around it.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I found this on the mailing list while trying to achieve the same.

For some page at `/static/truly-static.html` you could include this in Boot.scala and it will pass it on to Jetty/Tomcat/whatever

```
LiftRules.liftRequest.append {
  case Req("static" :: "truly-static" :: Nil, "html", _) => false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a more recent version of Lift (2.5 or 3.0), use

```
LiftRules.autoIncludeAjaxCalc.default.set(() => (session: LiftSession) 
=> false )
```